# Category wise Top Seller from Amazon MWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any way to get Amazon Top Sellers based on Category from Amazon MWS? I've searched but did not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that data isn't available from MWS.

Comment: You are wrong. Your link provides Top Selling Product, not Top Sellers.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood your question. Top Sellers are not available from MWS either.